# Retrieving RSS Feed from iTunes using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, ios, curl, rss, itunes

Been trying to get some PHP cURL code to work that gets the RSS feed from iTunes when you give it the podcast URL. Here is the code:

```
$inputString = "curl -A 'iTunes/12.1.1.4 (Windows; U; Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) DPI/96' -s 'https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/id530114975'";  
$input = shell_exec($inputString);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTML($input);
```

The cURL call when executed using shell_exec returns a blank string.
When I call the loadHTML function it gives the following error, which is pretty obvious given the cURL call doesn't return anything.....

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\php scripts\itunesFeedExtractor.php on line 130
```

Now, I got the PHP cURL code from somewhere else, haven't used it before, and tried to modify it to match my computers setup.... I've changed Windows version, service pack, build no. (Don't know why the DPI/96 is needed so I left it alone)

Comment: There' a PHP curl extension that you'd better use. No need to shell exec curl.

Comment: tried using the php curl extension as below but that still returned an empty string. wondering if the settings stuff in the curl call could be incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it working by adding to more curl_setopt() options. The full code now reads:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/id530114975");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "iTunes/12.1.1.4 (Windows; U; Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) DPI/96");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Cheers.....

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using the PHP curl extension:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/id530114975");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "iTunes/12.1.1.4 (Windows; U; Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) DPI/96");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But if you really want to use the shell_exec method, make sure curl is in your path - you can check by running the curl command from cmd / a terminal

Comment: Right, well I've installed the PHP cURL stuff and the curl_init() function is being found. But it is still returning an empty string like before. (curl was working from the command-line before btw)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "iTunes/12.1.1.4 (Windows; U; Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) DPI/96");$ch = curl_init("https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/id530114975");curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);Well it looks like I got it working by adding two extra settings.... The new PHP cURL version which works looks like this: